# Using multiprocessing with multiple return values and ordered dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, python-multiprocessing, markov-chains, ordereddictionary

I would like to use multiprocessing to generate the transition matrix of a Markov chain.

The function `generateKeys()` generates a dictionary with new rates and a dictionary with new keys for each state in the state space after making a transition.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def generateKeys():
    idxDict = OrderedDict()
    rateDict = OrderedDict()
    for key,state in stateDict.items():            
        newkeys,rates = transitionFunction(state)              
        idxDict[key] = newkeys
        rateDict[key] = rates
    return idxDict,rateDict
```

The reason to use `OrderedDict` here is that keys get mixed up with a regular `dict` in a next step (In the next step I concatenate the numpy arrays in the dictionaries and store them in a sparse coo_matrix).

Since dictionary keys are unique, it should be possible to run `generateKeys()` in parallel and fill up the two dictionaries much quicker on a multicore machine.

I have looked into the `multiprocessing` package and some examples, but the examples I saw were for a single return value and without ordered dictionaries. I don't really understand yet how to apply it in my setting. Can anyone show me how this works?

Comment: If you need to keep order for `transitionFunction` calls, parallelism isn't the way to go...

Comment: @Cyrbil Hmm, you are right. I already see a workaround for that by using regular dictionaries and sorting by keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `transitionFunction` can apply your states in any order:

```
transitionFunction('A')
transitionFunction('B')

# is equivalent to
transitionFunction('B')
transitionFunction('A')
```

You can use:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

p = Pool(cpu_count())
results = p.map(transitionFunction, stateDict.values())
```

`results` will have the same order than the values of `stateDict`, you can then build your dict with:

```
idxDict = dict(zip(stateDict.keys(), i[0] for i in results))
rateDict = dict(zip(stateDict.keys(), i[1] for i in results))
```

---

If `transitionFunction` can **not** apply your states in any order, then you will have unpredictable results...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think this should solve my problem. Now the next problem is that I can't call this from within a class: `p.map(self.transitionFunction,self.stateDict.values())` returns the following error:  `Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed` .

Comment: For this issue, refer to the many post already mentioning it: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=Can%27t%20pickle%20%3Ctype%20%27instancemethod%27%3E

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a solution for sharing a dictionary between independent processes. Look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) for a discription. IMHO it is the easiest way to handle your problem. However, this solution does not support `OrderedDict`. So if you can find a way to do it without them, it would work. Maybe you could pass/transform you dict afterwards into the desired form.